# Can symfony handle a plain HTML form?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a HTML form written in plain HTML (i.e. not using a `createFormBuilder` object) and I want my controller to handle the submission of that form in the same way that it would if I had created it using `createFormBuilder`.

My form's `path` is the same as the `@route` for the method in the controller, but I can't find an alternative to

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
if ($form->isSubmitted() ) {
}
```

Should I just do it the symfony way?

Answer (score 0):

Try it

**patch** is a your controller name and the action name

```
 <form class="formSearch" action="{{ path('patch') }}" method="POST">
     <input class="inputSearch" type="text" name="issn">


     <div class="">
         <button class="buttonSerch2" type="submit">serach</button>
     </div>
 </form>

 /**
 * @Route("/main/patch",name="patch")
 */
public function patchAction(Request $request)
{
if ($request->getMethod() == Request::METHOD_POST) {
$Issn =trim($request->get('issn'));


}
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Never mind. I found an article which appears to show what I'm trying to do.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/without_class.html

Comment: Hmmm.  The link you posted is about the data class.  You still need a form class.